# Как сделать функцию-счетчик?

Tags: python, функции, счетчики

Нужна функция, которая при первом вызове возвращает 1, при втором 2, при третьем 3 и т.д. Затрудняюсь в этом вопросе

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Без использования глобальных переменных (вместо этого используем [замыкание](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5))):

```
def create_counter():
    i = 0
    
    def func():
        nonlocal i
        i += 1
        return i
    
    return func


counter = create_counter()
print(counter())  # 1
print(counter())  # 2
print(counter())  # 3
```

С помощью вызова `create_counter()` можно создать сколько угодно функций-счетчиков, каждая будет работать независимо от другой.

Answer (score 5):

Если функция должна запоминать внутри себя состояние, то лучше это делать не через функции, а через классы:

```
class IncrementCounter:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self._value = 0
    
    def new_value(self):
        self._value += 1
        return self._value


# Пример использования

counter1 = IncrementCounter()

print(counter1.new_value())  # Выведет 1
print(counter1.new_value())  # Выведет 2
print(counter1.new_value())  # Выведет 3


# Можно создать ещё один экземпляр счётчика,
# и он будет работать независимо от первого

counter2 = IncrementCounter()

print(counter2.new_value())  # Выведет 1
print(counter2.new_value())  # Выведет 2


# Если мы теперь вернёмся к первому счётчику,
# то увидим, что на него не повлиияло то,
# что мы делали со вторым
# Первый счётчик по прежнему помнит,
# что его последним значением было 3, и сейчас должно быть 4

print(counter1.new_value())  # Выведет 4
```

Впрочем, для вашего случая можно использовать и функцию-генератор. Но тогда обращаться к такому счётчику нужно будет не через вызов, а через протокол итерации:

```
def increment_counter():
    value = 0
    while True:
        value += 1
        yield value


# Пример использования

counter1 = increment_counter()

print(next(counter1))  # Выведет 1
print(next(counter1))  # Выведет 2
print(next(counter1))  # Выведет 3
```

Причём для простого инкрементного счётчика уже есть готовая функция в стандартной библиотеке, так что можно не писать её самостоятельно, а взять готовую:

```
from itertools import count


counter1 = count(1)

# Работает так же, как и в примере выше

print(next(counter1))  # Выведет 1
print(next(counter1))  # Выведет 2
print(next(counter1))  # Выведет 3
```

Comment: Мне кажется вы усложняете. В любом типовом ЯП достаточно одной глобальной переменной и функции ее возвращающей++.

Comment: @Kromster, использование глобальных переменных - это плохая практика. Такой подход нормален в простых скриптиках на 20 строк, но в любом полноразмерном проекте глобальные переменные могут причинить много боли.

Comment: Если человек спрашивает такой тривиальный вопрос без уточнения размера проекта, то врядли у него там проект на 400к строк ;-) Скорее всего просто лабораторка или курсовая. Касательно глобальности - обычно есть несколько градаций, от глобальной общедоступной, до скрытой в классе или модуле. Вобщем было бы здорово, увидеть максимально простой вариант с припиской об его недостатках, а далее уже более "фен-шуйные" варианты )

Comment: @Kromster, вам ничего не мешает создать свой ответ

Comment: Мне мешает отсутствие знаний по Питону )

Answer (score 2):

Класс:

```
class Func():
    def __init__(self):
        self.c = 0
    def __call__(self):
        self.c += 1
        return self.c

func = Func()
print(func(), func(),func())
```

Фабрика:

```
def Func():
    c = 0
    def _func():
        nonlocal c
        c += 1
        return c
    return _func

func = Func()
print(func(), func(),func())
```

Глобальная переменная:

```
c = 0
def func():
    global c
    c += 1
    return c

print(func(), func(),func())
```

Answer (score 1):

как вариант, но так делать не стоит

```
def counter(__tmp=[0]):
    __tmp[0] += 1
    return __tmp[0]

print(counter())  # 1
print(counter())  # 2
print(counter())  # 3
```

Comment: Не могли бы обьяснить почему так не стоит делать?

Comment: наверное это вводит в заблуждение, в общем это скорее правило "хорошего тона", почитайте об "изменяемых типах в качестве параметров по умолчанию в Python"

Comment: @SuddenDumb по-хорошему аргументы функции должны использоваться только для передачи параметров, а не для хранения состояния. Поэтому да - так лучше не делать.